# Better way to do an alerting job in jenkins or alternative to do this

Tags: bash, jenkins, cron

I need a better way to use my alerting code.Right now I have a code that check for space free on aws ecs and sends a simple notification to slack if space is less than 5gb using slack api.I used this code in jenkins and setup a periodic schedule to run every 15 min.But once the notification is triggered I wanted it to stop the check for 4 hours so, it won't fill the slack channel with messages .So, i used sleep 14400 after condition is triggered.But this leaves an executor of jenkins waiting.Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a *better* way, you should use *better tools*. there are many tools (some free) out there, that can monitor something in a stateful manner (for example, using a daemon).

Writing to log (or slack channel) in this context of using Jenkins is sort of stateless, for example you cannot check whether an alarm is currently triggered or not.

Since you cannot check if an alarm is already triggered - using jenkins with the logic you requested in your question ('snooze feature') can be very ugly.

In general I would recommend using ***Conditional BuildStep*** to trigger a step if a condition is met (i.e. if alarm not already triggered), but since there is no way for you to poll this information, or achieve this with Jenkins without the solution being 'hackish' like creating a file to indicate alert is on, and deleting it from another job if it was created more than 4 hrs ago - I would suggest looking at tools more suitable for the job.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.I was asking for a better tool suggestion because I couldn't find a decent one.There is a tool called active experts but it is pretty horrible and only accepts Visual basic code.

Comment: Start with CloudWatch: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/optimizing-disk-usage-on-amazon-ecs/

Comment: No, I don't want to use cloud watch because cloud watch doesn't support slack webhook and also I cannot use my code on cloud watch for alerts.

Comment: Sure it does.. with SNS, example - http://notes.webutvikling.org/send-aws-cloudwatch-alarms-to-slack/

Comment: Ok.I want to use my own code rather than cloud watch.Please, suggest something for that.